# what does oauth2 refresh token actually contain?

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh-token

As we know that access token gives the client to access resources from resource server, I would like to know the contents and the process that happens with refresh token to get new access token.

I was tryging to experiment how oauth2 works, but got stuck at what refresh token does.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know the contents and the process that happens with
> refresh token to get new access token.

`Refresh token` are generally *opaque token* (random unique string).

`Refresh token` is used to get new `access token` from the `Authorization Server`. Refresh tokens typically remain valid for longer time as compared to access token. In a typical client-server flow, when the access token expired, server reject the request then client uses the earlier obtained refresh token to get a new access token from Authorization Server. By doing so authentication between client and server remain uninterrupted and no re-authentication needed. Once the refresh token expired, client has to go through the complete authentication flow which usually require user intervention.

[image: Refreshing an Expired Access Token Flow]